# Update Xcode to 9.0.1

Tags: macos, xcode, upgrade, high-sierra

I have already installed macOS High Sierra Version 10.13 and I have Xcode version 8.2.1. Now I want to update it to Xcode 9.0.1.

[image: About This Mac]

Do I directly install from the App Store using the following link?

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: If you want to update Xcode 9.0.1 you have to wait until Xcode 9.0.2beta or Xcode 9.0.2 are published. Please take the time to ask proper questions! Update: Xcode 9.0.0 > Xcode 9.0.1 Upgrade: Xcode 8.2.1 > Xcode 9.0.1. Additional read the system requirements for Xcode and some manuals or help files!

Comment: okay Thanks @klanomath but i am new to this community so dont have much idea about but can you please help me what i need to do to update my xcode version ? please

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the version of Xcode on the Mac App Store at the moment is 9.0.1, the latest version available. The version number is shown in the sidebar when viewing the product page.

Also in the sidebar is the compatibility for the app:

> Compatibility: macOS 10.12.6 or later

Therefore Xcode 9.0.1 can be installed on an up-to-date Sierra or any High Sierra installation.

Comment: but i want to know that mac OS Sierra 10.13 alow me to update xcode version 9.0.1

Comment: @Bhaumik Perhaps edit your question with this information to focus what you're asking for. I've updated my answer

Comment: okay Thanks @grgarside but i am new to this community so dont have much idea about but can you please help me what i need to do to update my xcode version ? please

Comment: @Bhaumik Use the link you provided to download and install Xcode from the Mac App Store. Please clarify exactly what you need assistance with?

Comment: okay thanks man..!!! my problem is solve Thanks for support..!!!